# Not able to install node-reggie in node v10.16.0

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish, npm-registry

I have used node-reggie to publish private node modules to our private registry.
Now we upgraded our node version from 0.12.17 to 10.16.0. 
After upgrade i am not able to install reggie in my local machine.
I am getting the following error.

[image]

Is it possible to install reggie in node v10.16.0 or is there any similar node module for publishing private node modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can do these if the project was working and after the update stopped. You do these.

```
npm cache clean --force 
npm update -g
```

If its a new project you can use

```
npm install reggie@latest
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ani.
the command should be npm install reggie@latest
But still the issue persists, since reggie is not updated for a long time.
I have used same version(0.2.1) of reggie in node v0.12.17